# Detecting when a SKNode is tapped on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, apple-watch, wktapgesturerecognizer

I'm writing an app for Apple Watch using SpriteKit, so I don't have access to functions like touchesBegan and I have to use a WKTapGestureRecognizer to detect taps, no big deal, but I have issues detecting taps on a node.
In my InterfaceController I have:

```
@IBAction func handleTap(tapGestureRecognizer: WKTapGestureRecognizer){
    scene?.didTap(tapGesture: tapGestureRecognizer)
}
```

And in my Scene file I have

```
func didTap(tapGesture:WKTapGestureRecognizer) {
    let position = tapGesture.locationInObject()
    let hitNodes = self.nodes(at: position)
    if hitNodes.contains(labelNode) {
    labelNode.text = "tapped!"
}
```

Problem is the Tap Gesture Recognizer gives me the absolute coordinates of the touch point (for example 11.0, 5,0) while my node is positioned relatively to the center of the screen (so its position is -0.99,-11.29 even though is at the center of the screen) therefore the tap is hitting the node not when actually tapping it, but when I tap on the top left of the screen. I searched everywhere and it looks like this is the way to do it yet I don't find people having the same issues. The node has been added via the editor. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So you have the right idea. You are getting this wrong because hitNodes is an array of SKNodes. Those are newly created. So when you use hitNodes.contains the addresses of the labelNode and the address of the newly created SKNode that is being compared would be completely different. Therefore it would never be tapped.

Here's what I would do. This would be in my Scene File. Your InterfaceController class is correct.

```
func didTap(tapGesture:WKTapGestureRecognizer) {
    let position = tapGesture.locationInObject()
    if labelNode.contains(position) {
        labelNode.text = "tapped!"
    }
}
```

OR another way would be this. I like this way because you only have one function which would be in the WKInterfaceControlller And you would need no functions in your Scene File.

```
@IBAction func tapOnScreenAct(_ sender: WKGestureRecognizer) {
    if scene.labelNode.contains(sender.locationInObject()) {
        scene.labelNode.text = "tapped!"
    }    
}
```

Either way, both should work. Let me know if you have any more questions or clarifications.